# Encapsulate intersect type into interface

Tags: typescript

I see myself writing the following everywhere:

```
product: Product & { id: string; };
```

How do I write an interface, so that instead I can write

```
product: WithId<Product>;
```

I tried something like this, but the compiler doesn't like extending from generics:

```
export interface WithId<T> extends T {
    id: string;
}
```

Comment: Why not use a type alias instead of an interface here? Btw: union is `|`, but you use `&` in code

Comment: ah you're right, used the wrong name. fixed it. type alias is the way to go indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a type intersection

```
export type WithId<T> = { [K in keyof T]: T[keyof T] } & { id: string }


interface product { myNew: string }
let et: WithId<product> = { myNew: "s", id: "s" } // ok
let et: WithId<product> = { test: "s", id: "s" } // error
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact, `export type WithId<T> = T & { id: string };` seems to be sufficient!

Answer (score 2):

You can abstract the construct by abstraction of `& {id: string}`

```
export type WithId<T> = T & { id: string }

type Example = WithId<{ a: number }> // {a: number, id: string}
const example: Example = {a: 1, id: 'id'}
```

PS. `{ [K in keyof T]: T[keyof T] }` is nothing different like `T` itself, so redundant.